# Reducing time complexity for Python, finding numbers with same digits

Tags: python, performance, math

I'm writing code that returns the next bigger number with the same digits. I thought that my solution was pretty fast, but when testing it I've realized that my time complexity is really bad.

```
def next_bigger(n):
    j = n
    for i in range(n):
        n+=1
        if sorted(str(j)) == sorted(str(n)):
            return n
    return -1

print(next_bigger(143255555555555553223))
```

Is there a faster way of implementing this algorithm. Is there a way for me to replace sorted() and remove the for loop?

Note: if it can't find a bigger number it returns -1. Forgot to add, thought it was clear.

Note 2: Sorry, I'm bad at writing questions. The original algorithm had while True instead of a for loop. That's why it returns -1 when running it as is, having while True will give the correct answer but it will take time.

Some inputs: 123 -> 132 || 2532 -> 3225 || 543890432 -> 543892034 ||
143255555555555553223 -> 143255555555555553232 ||

Comment: What do you expect to be returned in the case of `11`? It's unclear if all digits must be used.

Comment: Not only is your algorithm pretty slow, but it's also not correct. `print(next_bigger(1999))` erroneously prints `-1`, instead of `9199`.

Comment: @Stef I'm *pretty* sure the OP means that if `1999` is entered the response should be `-1` since `9199` is larger than the original number, and `999` doesn't include `1`.

Comment: @NathanielFord I don't understand your comment. The OP is looking for the *next bigger number with the same digits*. There are only 4 numbers with the same digits as 1999: 1999, 9199, 9919 and 9991. The next bigger number after 1999 is 9199.

Comment: @stef I might have a misunderstanding as to what the OP is looking for - if I have the numbers 1, 2 and 3, I would say '3 is the biggest' and '2 is the next biggest'. Suggesting they're looking for a smaller number - but I agree you could parse it that they're looking for a larger number, which is in line with their code. Clarification with examples would help! OP: give us a few sample inputs and what you expect to have happen!

Comment: @Psychicplatypus I strongly suggest trying to solve the problem "by hand" on a few examples. Once you have succesfully done that, formulating an efficient algorithm will be much easier. Consider the number `48302698543`. What should be the next bigger? Figure it out by hand, without help of a computer. Then try to understand how you figured it out. Obviously you're not going to try every number 48302698544, 48302698545, 48302698546, 48302698547, 48302698548... in order. That would be incredibly slow.

Comment: @NathanielFord I have no doubt - next bigger means bigger, and the code given in the question is iterating on numbers bigger than n (`n+=1` in the for-loop), until it finds one that has the same digits (`sorted(str(j)) == sorted(str(n))`). This code is terribly inefficient because the for-loop iterates on natural numbers 1 by 1, rather than trying to permute the digits of n. And it fails in some cases, because the loop only goes up to 2*n, so if the next bigger number is larger than two times n, it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You fundamental problem is that you're starting with the most significant digit and working forward from there, when you want to start with your least significant digit and find the least other significant digit that it can replace.

Thus: if you have the number `432`, the `2` wants to swap with the `3` so as to create `423`, the next smallest number with the same digits. That means, starting at the smallest number you want to look at each increasing digit in increasing significance order. (In the above example, first at `3` then at `4`). The first digit that the least significant digit is smaller than, it should replace. Finally, if there are no numbers that are bigger than it (i.e. `419` - the 9 is the largest digit), you should try again, but starting at the second to last number, and so on. Only if you exhaust all digits in this manner should you return a false value.

At best this approach gives an O(len(n)^2) time, though, since it requires a double iteration (for each digit, starting at the last and moving forward, check each digit starting at the second to last and move forward). There might be a better way I'm not thinking of.

There are edge cases to handle (what if you n is 0 or 1 length? What happens with the number `100`?), but this is the core of what you're going for:

```
for alpha in range(len(n), -1, -1):
    alpha_num = n[alpha]
    for omega in range(len(n-1), -1, -1):
        omega_num = n[omega]
        if alpha_num < omega_num:
            n[omega] = alpha_num
            n[alpha] = omega_num
            return n
```

**Addendum: Next *largest* number**

Based on comments made, I suspect I misinterpreted the goal. It is not that you want to find some number `b` that is strictly less than `a` and utilizes all the same digits, as well as being the largest of all such numbers, but rather you want to find a `b` that is strictly larger than `a` and also uses all the same digits and is the smallest of all such numbers.

Thus you might have these examples:

```
432 -> No result
567 -> 576
627 -> 672
587 -> 758
672 -> 726
```

You're going to want to utilize a similar approach, starting with your least significant digits and working to the left to find the smallest number that is still larger and swap. This doesn't cover all the cases though. (I'll return to this when I have more than a minute to write out the algorithm, but maybe this helps set you in the right direction.)

Comment: *"At best this approach gives an O(n^2) time"* This statement is incredibly confusing. In the OP's question, `n` is the original number, not the number of digits of that number. The OP's algorithm is iterating on numbers directly. But your suggestion is to operate on the digits of `n`, which would be much more efficient than the OP's approach. In fact, your approach sounds very close to the [next permutation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order), which is linear in the number of digits, not quadratic as you suggest.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by *"You fundamental problem is that you're starting with the most significant digit and working forward from there"*.

Comment: @Stef I disagree that that is 'incredibly' confusing, since `n` is both idiomatic for the 'length of input' and in this case `n` isn't even a number - it's an array of characters. But regardless, I clarified that I meant the length.

Comment: it might be idiomatic for you, but it's clearly not that obvious for the OP. In the code shown by the OP, n is an integer, not a list of characters.

Comment: @Stef I think you're being unnecessarily combative in your comments. I made a modification, unless that doesn't take it from 'incredibly unclear' to 'clear' in your book, I'm not sure further comment is necessary?